# How do you filter down (ns-map *ns*) to show only the functions defined in the current namespace?

Tags: clojure

How do you filter down `(ns-map *ns*)` to show only the functions defined in the current namespace? I don't want to see all the import functions, but just the ones defined in the current namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(ns-interns *ns*)` for everything (functions and other values)

This shows only functions:

```
(filter #(and (bound? %) (fn? @%)) (vals (ns-interns *ns*)))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
;; prints a load of stuff including clojure.core
(ns-map (the-ns 'clojure.set))
;; prints only clojure.set vars
(ns-publics (the-ns 'clojure.set))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will do the job:

```
(filter #(= (.name *ns*) (.name (.ns  %))) 
  (filter var? (vals (ns-map *ns*))))
```

The only question is - if it will compatible with future versions of Clojure?

Comment: This seems similar to the definition for ns-interns.